# django still uses StatReloader even though watchman & pywatchman are installed

Tags: python-3.x, django, watchman

I wanted to slow down the auto-reload feature of django's runserver for 7 seconds. While searching for a solution, I read on the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#s-runserver that I should install `Watchman` as well as `pywatchman` and that django will use that instead for which I can add a `timeout` period for reload after file change.
I also read on https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/01/20/efficient-reloading-in-djangos-runserver-with-watchman/ that after installation django's runserver will show `Watching for file changes with WatchmanReloader` instead of `Watching for file changes with StatReloader`.

I also add a `.watchmanconfig` like this:

```py
{"ignore_dirs": [".git", ".vscode", "venv", "htmlcov", "media", ]}
```

But on mine it still uses `StatReloader` even though `watchman` & `pywatchman` are installed in accordance with their doc.

```py
django version: 4.1.2
python version: 3.8.16
watchman version: 20221225.010033.0
pywatchman version: 1.4.1
```

Can anybody help?

My gratitude before hand

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an issue with `pywatchman` (see: https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/970).

You can consider downloading watchfiles and django-watchfiles as suggested here: https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/970#issuecomment-1191330203.